# How to permanently format data in Excel/Sheets as to remove the original value from the cell?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formatting, pivot-table

I have a list of dates in the format '05/12/2023' etc. I've then formatted these values to simply be 'December 2023'.

However, the formatting doesn't remove the original 05/12/2023. This presents an issue when creating a pivot table. This is because the pivot table considers there to be multiple different December 2023s as a result of there being data points for 05/12/2023, 06/12/2023, 07/12/2023.

My issue is that I cannot just format the data points as text since I want to be able to sort them in monthly order at the point of the pivot table. To keep the data tidy, I cannot sort them in the original sheet.

I've tried a paste special pasting the values only. This doesn't work and keeps the original value. Secondly, I do not want a manual method for this. When new values are added to the spreadsheet I don't want an extra step but an automatic process. The only real modifications I foresee as being appropriate are through the creation of new columns.

Expected pivot table:

| December 2023 | January 2024 | February 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |

Current pivot table (as a result of 05/12/2023, 06/12/2023, 07/12,2023):

| December 2023 | December 2023 | December 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |
| Value. | Value. | Value. |

Comment: So do a countifs() or sumifs() to get a single value per month. As for the date value, it is a serial number that is then formatted to whatever you choose, just the year or year and month or a week number.

Comment: Check [Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725). It does exactly what you need. You can group by Year and Month even if the dates are different.

Comment: Please focus your question on **either** Excel **or** Google Sheets. They are *different* technologies.